# What is this metal roof trim that was torn loose by a storm?

Tags: trim, roofing, siding, damage

Heard a banging, couldn’t put my finger on it while I was up in the attic but I found out where in the house it was. Walked outside and found the culprit.

[image]

It’s the metal trim, perhaps this is the fascia? I’m not too roomy savvy but I’ll be able to take a better look at it in a day or two.

So what is it? Just some aluminum trip piece that attaches to the end trusses?

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is the rake board, or the metal that covers the rake boards. It supposed to be held in place by pop rivets and/or nails and tucked under the metal drip edge that is part of the roof system. It could be reattached, but it surely dented, if not cracked where the repeated bending has occurred from all the flapping in the wind it has done. It should be replaced for best results, but could be set back in place until it can get repaired properly

Comment: I plan to replace it, should be a quick fix id imagine. Who would handle something like this? Roofer or siding company? Could very well be a DIY if I don’t have to disturb the roof, do I?

Comment: It can be a DIY, remove the old piece, noting how it is fastened. The replacement should be available, it might take some searching through the big box stores or check a roofing/siding supply house. You should be able to replace it without disturbing the roof. There is a chance the nails that hold it in place are under the drip edge. Lift it slightly if need be to check if they are.

Comment: I’m not one to shy away from a DIY. No rain projected here in the next few days either. It’s called a rake board cover? Any chance you may have a better name or a link to a typical product at a big box I can get a bearing off of?

Comment: I mention "technically" because the trim piece is located on the rake of the house, but the material is the same that is used as fascia trim. It may be a standard piece as in would be readily available. But i would find the lead on the material and take the piece you have and match it up. It should be bent like a "J", or possibly an "L".

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/6-in-x-12-ft-White-Aluminum-Fascia-Trim-77103/204103285?mtc=SEM-B-F_D22-G-D22-22_3_SIDING-Generic-NA-NA-DSA-NA-NA-Broadience_Test_OG2021&cm_mmc=SEM-B-F_D22-G-D22-22_3_SIDING-Generic-NA-NA-DSA-NA-NA-Broadience_Test_OG2021-71700000080996877-58700006795822299-39700061438583292&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0oCDBhCPARIsAII3C_HWyRvO5ZTBnMhLXO4OhKvlR1zuHe_78IaMQj-1V4Tg-V7h6XUjDvkaAk_WEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: What is “the lead”?

Comment: Lead is just a term for getting the info on where to get your materials

Comment: A siding contractor probably custom  bent that metal trim.   If you are going to hire the fix start by finding a good vinyl siding contractor.

Comment: Take the old piece to a local sheet metal shop, anyone with a metal brake can bend a piece like that no problem. Your only issue can be matching colors.